# Can not create UserControl inside new AppDomain

Tags: c#, wpf, appdomain

When i load assembly(xxx.dll) into new AppDomain and trying to create UserControl there, occurs the exception:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'xxx.resources' or one of its dependencies.
```

When i load the assembly into Main AppDomain it works fine.
Why the exception occurs?

```
public void InitializeComponent() {
if (_contentLoaded) {
      return;
}
_contentLoaded = true;
```

//HERE THE EXCEPTION OCCURS

```
System.Uri resourceLocater = new System.Uri("/Company.AddInApp;component/controls/usercontrol.xaml", System.UriKind.Relative);

#line 1 "..\..\..\Controls\UserControl1.xaml" stem.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(this, resourceLocater);
#line default
#line hidden
}
```

Comment: SOS guys... need help....

Comment: You should debug this with fusion log viewer - http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BackToBasicsUsingFusionLogViewerToDebugObscureLoaderErrors.aspx

Comment: The "fusion log" said me nothing, it just show which assemblies are missed in the search path(AppDomain base directory).
Also it adds locale(ex: en-EN) directory to search from... (((

Comment: So, does `xxx.resources` assembly actually exist in any of the path it searched for? If not, then what path it exists in?

Comment: The "xxx.resources" assembly is not exists...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the mistake:

```
var setup = new AppDomainSetup
{
        ApplicationBase = rootAddInsPath,
         ........
};
var appDomain = AppDomain.CreateDomain(...)

//I don't must do this here!!!
appDomain.AssemblyResolve += (sender, args) =>
{
     ....
}

var managerType = typeof(AddInLoadManager);
var manager =(AddInLoadManager)appDomain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(managerType.Assembly.FullName, managerType.FullName);
```

Correct place for the "AppDomain.AssemblyResolve" event is inside of the "AddInLoadManager" class.

Thanks for your help @YK1